# What's the most efficient way to cancel a parallel_for

Tags: c++, mfc, for-loop, parallel-processing

What's the most efficient way to get out of a parallel_for?
To get out of a standard for loop, we do the following :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i+)
{
    bool bValue = DoSomething();

   //Break if bValue is true
   if(bValue)
      break;
}
```

I did some research and I found some info on [Cancellation in the PPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984117%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#algorithms)
 and I'm considering 3 options

-Task Group

```
// To enable cancelation, call parallel_for in a task group.
structured_task_group tg;

task_group_status status = tg.run_and_wait([&] 
{
   parallel_for(0, 100, [&](int i) 
   {

      bool bValue = DoSomething();
      if (bValue)
      {
         tg.cancel();
      }
   });
});
```

-Throw an exception

```
try
{
   parallel_for(0, 100, [&](int i) 
   {
      bool bValue = DoSomething();
      if (bValue)
          throw i;
   });
}
catch (int n)
{
   wcout << L"Caught " << n << endl;
}
```

-Use a boolean

```
// Create a Boolean flag to coordinate cancelation.
bool bCanceled = false;

parallel_for(0, 100, [&](int i) 
{       
   // Perform work if the task is not canceled.
   if (!bCanceled)
   {
       bool bValue = DoSomething();
       if (bValue)
          bCanceled = true;
   }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to structure your code so that you don't cancel a parallel-for? Because that's really not a thing you should *want* to do.

Comment: Why is this not good? I mean, in a normal for, you don't want to do 300000 loops if you can stop after 10 (if the condition is true).

Comment: @Nicol Bolas : In most cases, that's what I would do. However, some loops are too complex to be rewritten.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCôté: Generally, `parallel_for` is a simple tool for a simple problem: I have a bunch of heavy-weight tasks I want to execute, and I want them done in parallel. `parallel_for` takes care of all of the minutiae. Once you start wanting to do things that `parallel_for` clearly isn't designed to do (like stopping halfway), then you clearly want a more powerful mechanism than `parallel_for`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `structured_task_group` option is the only one that would actually be reasonable. #3 is simply massively unsafe, and #2 is simply a horrific abuse of exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Visual Studio 2012, there is a `run_with_cancellation_token` function that will execute a lambda along with a `cancellation_token`. Inside the lambda,

Link: [run_with_cancellation_token Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh749944.aspx)

A code example can be found on MSDN at: [How to: Use Cancellation to Break from a Parallel Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547146.aspx)

I cannot speak for the "efficiency" of this approach, as I suspect that C++ exception is involved in its implementation. However, this code might be simpler than other approaches, and it allows the use of most PPL constructs without being limited to `structured_task_group`.